# Loading CodeMirror with RequireJS from CDN

Tags: javascript, requirejs, cdn, codemirror

I want to make an online javascript demo and I want to allow users to alter demo behavior through changing the code. My project uses RequireJS with big success so I decided to stick with it. First I tried to load editor through absolute URL paths:

```
require(
  [
        "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.13.4/codemirror.js",
        "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.13.4/mode/javascript/javascript.js",
        "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.13.4/addon/comment/continuecomment.js",
        "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.13.4/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js",
        "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.13.4/addon/comment/comment.js"
  ],
  (CodeMirror)=>{
        var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
          lineNumbers: true,
          matchBrackets: true,
          continueComments: "Enter",
          extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Q": "toggleComment"}
        });
  }
);
```

Require JS tries to load this path then: `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.13.4/lib/codemirror` That's obviously wrong because

1. I didn't ask it to put `/lib/` in front of my path, so why did it do so?
2. `.js` is missing.

After that failure, I tried to configure requireJS and use relative paths:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        codemirror: [
            "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.13.4/"
        ]
    },
    waitSeconds: 20   
});

require(
  [
        "codemirror/codemirror",
        "codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript",
        "codemirror/addon/comment/continuecomment",
        "codemirror/addon/edit/matchbrackets",
        "codemirror/addon/comment/comment"
  ],
  (CodeMirror)=>{
        var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
          lineNumbers: true,
          matchBrackets: true,
          continueComments: "Enter",
          extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Q": "toggleComment"}
        });
  }
);
```

This time, `.js` is there but the path is still wrong: `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.13.4//lib/codemirror.js` Notice the double slash.

I didn't ask RequireJS to put random stuff in the path I specified, so why does it do so? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that codemirror is normally packaged such that the `codemirror.js` file is in the `/lib` directory, however the way it is hosted on **cdnjs** is that it's in the root directory. Your problem then arises when you try to load an add-on which then tries to load `../../lib/codemirror` - which does not exist because of the aforementioned hosting difference.

I got it to work with something like this:

```
requirejs.config({paths:{
    codemirror:'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.14.2',
    'codemirror/lib':'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.14.2'}
});
requirejs(["codemirror/lib/codemirror", "codemirror/addon/comment/continuecomment"],
function(CodeMirror) {
});
```